# Vue.js not working in c#, returning the curly braces

Tags: c#, vue.js

I have the following in my ASP.NET Framework application but when run my application it returns `{{message}}` and not the expected `hello world`.

```html
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: () => {
                return {
                    message: "hello world"
                }
            }
        });

    </script>       

<div id="app">

     <p>{{message}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your example is identical to [this one](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/).   I suggest you [follow the tutorial on scrimba](https://scrimba.com/p/pXKqta/cQ3QVcr).

Comment: I've followed the example, but I still run into the same problem

Comment: Well, we need more information than this.  Presumably you're not running the same environment as scrimba is.

Comment: put your  `new vue` script after `div id="app"`